# Creating a function for a simple menu equation

Tags: python, function, equation

I'm very new to coding and I've managed to create the equation but I just can't wrap my head around the function side of things - The task is to create a menu which adds 20% VAT - 10% discount and 4.99 delivery fee - I was originally going to repeat the equation and change the price variable but a function would be much better and will require less coding but I just can't figure out how to perform it - Any help would be appreciated.

````
def menu():
    print("[1] I7 9700k")
    print("[2] GTX 1080 graphics card")
    print("[3] SSD 2 Tb")


price = 399;
discount_percentage = 0.9;
taxed_percentage = 1.2;
Delivery_cost = 4.50;

Vat_price = (price*taxed_percentage)
Fin_price = (Vat_price*discount_percentage)
Final_price = (Fin_price+Delivery_cost)

print("Final price including delivery:", "£" + str(Final_price))

menu()
option = int(input("Enter your option: "))

while option != 0:
    if option ==1:
        print("I will add equations later :)")
    elif option ==3:
        print("I will add")
    else:
        print("You numpty")

    print()
    menu()
    option = int(input("Enter your option: "))```
````

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have a function for `menu()` I am going to assume the difficulty is in passing the values. You can define the function as follows:

```
def get_total_price(price, discount, tax, delivery_cost):
    price *= tax
    price *= discount
    price += delivery_cost
    return price

product_price = get_total_price(399, 0.9, 1.2, 4.50)
```

If the tax, discount and delivery are the same each time, you can hard-code those values into the function and only give the price as a variable as such:

```
def get_total_price(price):
    price *= 1.2
    price *= 0.9
    price += 4.5
    return price

product_price = get_total_price(399)
```